# No Httpd.config rewrite Uppercase to Lowercase characters

Tags: url-rewriting

Unfortunately I do not have acces to Httpd.config file because of my hosting. But I really need to Rewrite all Uppercase characters in URL to lowercase.

Now I have the following:

Redirect 301 /korting/CompAny1/ http://www.web.nl/korting/company1/

Redirect 301 /korting/CompaNy2/ http://www.web.nl/korting/company2/

Is there a rewrite rule to lowercase everything? I have a Wordpress installation so a plugin or php script would also be fine....

This question is asked a lot of times and a lot of answers don't work or require 
Httpd.config

Comment: Anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Finally!!

An answer that didn't broke my site and actually works!

**EDIT: unfortunately after a few minutes my site broke down......**

```
# Skip next two rules if lowercasing in progress (Remove this rule if case-conversion plug-in below is removed) 
RewriteCond %{ENV:qLow} ^yes$ [NC] 
RewriteRule . - [S=2] 
# Prevent recursion and over-writing of myURI and myQS 
RewriteCond %{ENV:qRed} ^yes$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .? - [L] 
# Get the client-requested full URI and full query string 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ (/[^?]*)(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule .? - [E=myURI:%1,E=myQS:%2] 
# Uppercase to lowercase conversion plug-in (This section, along with the first noted rule above, may be removed if not needed or wanted) Skip next 28 rules if no uppercase letters in URL 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ![A-Z] 
RewriteRule .? - [S=28] 
# Else swap them out, one at a time 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1a%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1b%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1c%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1d%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1e%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1f%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1g%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1h%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1i%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1j%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1k%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1l%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1m%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1n%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1o%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1p%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1q%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1r%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1s%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1t%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1u%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1v%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1w%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1x%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1y%2] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ 
RewriteRule . - [E=myURI:%1z%2] 
# Set lowercasing-in-progress flag 
RewriteRule . - [E=qLow:yes] 
# If any uppercase characters remain, re-start mod_rewrite processing from the beginning 
RewriteCond %{ENV:myURI} [A-Z] 
RewriteRule . - [N] 
# If any characters were lowercased, set redirect required flag and reset lowercasing-in-progress flag (S=28 from above lands here) 
RewriteCond %{ENV:qLow} ^yes$ [NC] 
RewriteRule . - [E=qRed:yes,E=qLow:done] 
# End Uppercase to lowercase conversion plug-in 
RewriteCond %{ENV:qRed} ^yes$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{ENV:myURI}%{ENV:myQS} [R=301,L]
```